# Custom Django Wagtailmenus Flatmenu Template

Tags: django, django-templates, wagtail

I am using https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmenus for my Django Wagtail menus, but can't seem to figure out how to use a custom template for my `flat_menu`.  I followed the guides but I think I may be doing something wrong.

My flat_menu template is in a directory `menus/top_sub_menu.html`, where `top_sub_menu` is the handle of the menu I created.

**top_sub_menu.html**

```
{% load menu_tags %}
{% if menu_items %}
  <ul class="c-links c-theme-ul">
    {% for item in menu_items %}
      <li>
        <a href="{{ item.href }}">{{ item.text }}</a> {% if item.has_children_in_menu %}{% sub_menu item %}{% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
{% endif %}
```

**header.html**

```
{% load menu_tags %}
...
{% flat_menu 'top_sub_menu' %}
...
```

I have a custom `main_menu.html` and a `sub_menu.html` in the same directory and they work, so I know my menu directory is in correct location. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template location behaviour described in the README for the `{% flat_menu %}` tag (https://github.com/rkhleics/wagtailmenus#4-using-the--flat_menu--tag) was only introduced in version `2.2.0`. You should be able to use your custom template by utilising the `template` argument, though. For example:

**In header.html**

```
{% load menu_tags %}
...
{% flat_menu 'top_sub_menu' template="menus/top_sub_menu.html" %}
...
```